# Navigation Controller and View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I need return to the principal view , when i press the button in the first view of the navigation controller....

I have connect one simple view and this view go to the navigation controller..

ViewController --> Navigation Controller --> View of Navigation

```
<----------------------------------------------
```

How i can do this....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to return to the top Root ViewController :

```
navigationController?.popTopRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

if you want to return into the previous viewController:

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: When i press the botton , not do the return

Comment: this is my code of my botton:
`code`
@IBAction func rtnHomeM(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        println("WTF")
    }

Comment: did you connect the bar button to the button in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

To answer this using IB:

[image]

CTRL + Drag your button to your VC and create a modal segue.